Does Salesforce handle asynchronous platform event publishing errors for events published by flow?
From the documentation I can see that if I publish a platform event in Apex, I can use the EventBus.EventPublishCallback interface to handle the scenario if an error occurs during the publishing of a platform event (which occurs asynchronously).
What is the recommended approach to handling/logging asynchronous publishing errors when platform events are published via the 'create records' element in a flow?
I am making the assumption that adding a fault path following the element can only deal with any synchronous issues that arise from queuing the event.
